# Merge in oracle shows Error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to execute a query

```
merge into RAWREQUEST
using ( select APP_TXN_SEQ_ID,APP_TXN_ID from SEQ_APP_TIN_MAP )
on (RAWREQUEST.app_txn_id=SEQ_APP_TIN_MAP.app_txn_id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE set  RAWREQUEST.app_txn_id = SEQ_APP_TIN_MAP.APP_TXN_SEQ_ID
```

it shows

```
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
```

Comment: What you've posted gets ORA-00904, not ORA-00905. You also can't update a column you're using in the `on` condition (ORA-38104, from trying to set `RAWREQUEST.app_txn_id`). I think you're going to need a correlated update here.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions possible:

*Give the inline table an alias*

```
merge into RAWREQUEST
using ( select APP_TXN_SEQ_ID,APP_TXN_ID from SEQ_APP_TIN_MAP ) t
on (RAWREQUEST.app_txn_id = t.app_txn_id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE set RAWREQUEST.app_txn_id = t.APP_TXN_SEQ_ID
```

*Use the table `SEQ_APP_TIN_MAP` directly instead of an inline table*

```
merge into RAWREQUEST
using SEQ_APP_TIN_MAP
on (RAWREQUEST.app_txn_id=SEQ_APP_TIN_MAP.app_txn_id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE set  RAWREQUEST.app_txn_id = SEQ_APP_TIN_MAP.APP_TXN_SEQ_ID
```

Comment: That looks like valid SQL. Can you provide the table structures or an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) ?